# CreateWindow doesn't exist in user32.dll any more

Tags: delphi, winapi, windows-10

I found out that `CreateWindowA` and `CreateWindowW` don't exist in `user32.dll` file of Windows 10 anymore. Have you seen any announcements from Microsoft about this?

I found this out when I noticed that in Delphi's `Winapi.Windows` file they are emulated.

**Update**

It seems that I overlooked that in Delphi 6 these functions were also macros that use `CreateWindowEx`. Probably David is right and these functions only had DLL entry points in Win16. They definitely weren't there in Windows XP SP3.

Comment: Not even user32.dll 6.1.7601.24546 (Win7x64) exports this name, so Win10 can't be the first one.

Comment: @AmigoJack I expect that these functions were never exported in Win32, and that they date back to Win16.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan seems so: user32.dll 4.00.950 (Win95, still got the CD) doesn't export this name either (only `CreateWindowExW` and `A`). Did OP jump directly from Win3 to Win10?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`CreateWindowA` is a macro for `CreateWindowExA`, and `CreateWindowW` is a macro for `CreateWindowExW`, both of which do exist in user32.dll on Windows 10.

From `winuser.h`:

```cpp
#define CreateWindowA(lpClassName, lpWindowName, dwStyle, x, y,\
nWidth, nHeight, hWndParent, hMenu, hInstance, lpParam)\
CreateWindowExA(0L, lpClassName, lpWindowName, dwStyle, x, y,\
nWidth, nHeight, hWndParent, hMenu, hInstance, lpParam)
#define CreateWindowW(lpClassName, lpWindowName, dwStyle, x, y,\
nWidth, nHeight, hWndParent, hMenu, hInstance, lpParam)\
CreateWindowExW(0L, lpClassName, lpWindowName, dwStyle, x, y,\
nWidth, nHeight, hWndParent, hMenu, hInstance, lpParam)
```

Answer (score 10):

I'm afraid that the premise of your question is incorrect. The Delphi 6 `Windows` unit does not link to `CreateWindowW` or `CreateWindowA`. Here is how these functions are actually implemented:

```
function CreateWindow(lpClassName: PChar; lpWindowName: PChar;
  dwStyle: DWORD; X, Y, nWidth, nHeight: Integer; hWndParent: HWND;
  hMenu: HMENU; hInstance: HINST; lpParam: Pointer): HWND;
begin
  Result := CreateWindowEx(0, lpClassName, lpWindowName, dwStyle, X, Y,
    nWidth, nHeight, hWndPar, hMenu, hInstance, lpParam);
end;
function CreateWindowA(lpClassName: PAnsiChar; lpWindowName: PAnsiChar;
  dwStyle: DWORD; X, Y, nWidth, nHeight: Integer; hWndParent: HWND;
  hMenu: HMENU; hInstance: HINST; lpParam: Pointer): HWND;
begin
  Result := CreateWindowExA(0, lpClassName, lpWindowName, dwStyle, X, Y,
    nWidth, nHeight, hWndParent, hMenu, hInstance, lpParam);
end;
function CreateWindowW(lpClassName: PWideChar; lpWindowName: PWideChar;
  dwStyle: DWORD; X, Y, nWidth, nHeight: Integer; hWndParent: HWND;
  hMenu: HMENU; hInstance: HINST; lpParam: Pointer): HWND;
begin
  Result := CreateWindowExW(0, lpClassName, lpWindowName, dwStyle, X, Y,
    nWidth, nHeight, hWndParent, hMenu, hInstance, lpParam);
end;
```

As you can see, this mirrors their implementation in the Windows header files as demonstrated by [tenfour's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64240285/505088).

If you have code that is failing because it attempts to import functions named `CreateWindowW` or `CreateWindowA` from `user32`, then the problem is not that `user32` has changed, it is that your code is simply wrong to expect functions with those names to exist at all.